# Why does my do..while loop not execute the setTimeout within the async-await code correctly?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, do-while

I have a do..while loop that executes a promise and awaits the response.  The loop needs to continue while the response is either "Processing" or "Received".  However, there is a setTimeout function within the Promise.

The goal here is that the function, `respo = await promise1.then(resp => resp)`, within the "do" statement of the do..while loop, gets called only after 2 seconds.  This is merely to allow the API which I am using, to complete its work.

What currently happens is that the setTimeout is called once and the loop keeps repeating the same response virtually immediately, indicating that the 2-second break does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

```
const promise1 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    resolve(tasks(resStatus.data.task.id, tokenTenant))
  }, 2000);
})

do {
  respo = await promise1
  console.log(respo.data)
} while (respo.data.status === "Processing" || respo.data.status === "Received");
```

.
.
.

*Some sample responses (problem resolved) for those who are curios:*

```
ALL SYSTEMS GO!
{ id: 'd23b2cf3-02c3-48fe-9479-1407238d41d9',
  status: 'Received',
  result: null,
  tenant_id: 'eaa55f40-93fa',
  creation_time: '2019-04-25T18:19:47+0000' }

****...some results omitted for brievety...****

{ id: 'd23b2cf3-02c3-48fe-9479-1407238d41d9',
  status: 'Processing',
  result: null,
  tenant_id: 'eaa55f40-93fa',
  creation_time: '2019-04-25T18:19:47+0000' }
{ id: 'd23b2cf3-02c3-48fe-9479-1407238d41d9',
  status: 'Failed',
  result: { Reason: '[Errno 22] Invalid argument' },
  tenant_id: 'eaa55f40-93fa',
  creation_time: '2019-04-25T18:19:47+0000' }
```

Comment: A promise can only resolve once, and then remains resolved. The promise constructor callback is always executed once, and once only.

Comment: `.then(resp => resp)`  is like doing `resp = resp` in synchronous code, it's essentially a no-op.

Comment: Ah, thanks @trincot .  What would you recommend is the best and cleanest alternative?

Comment: Move the `const promise1 = ` inside the loop. That way you create a new promise each iteration.

Comment: Hi @BenjaminGruenbaum, that was a typo from old code.  I have fixed it just before you posted your reply.  :)

Comment: @trincot that should be an answer and not a comment :]

Comment: Ok @trincot, will do, test and let you know shortly.

Comment: I posted an answer, but it would be useful to know what `tasks` returns. If it is a promise, you should really not create a new promise with `new Promise`.

Comment: To simplify even further, I'd make that condition: `while( ["Processing",  "Received"].includes(respo.data.status) ) ` (less typing)

Comment: @trincot.  I am submitting a POST request to my server that configures some networking equipment.  The server immediately accepts the POST request and provides a task ID.   I then need to use the ID to submit a GET request to query the status of the configuration of the networking equipment.   The average time to conf a device, depending on its transport medium (fibre or microwave) ranges from a few milliseconds to 10 seconds.   Therefore I need to query the Server until I receive either a "Success" or "Failed" response.   I will add another comment with sample data

Comment: I don't think I can add code snippets to comments.  Will try and add to my question

Comment: I am more interested to see what the `tasks` function returns. Is it a promise or is it a synchronously returned response?

Comment: ah ok.  It's an async:  

`async function tasks(
  task_id, tokenTenant
) {
  return axios({
    method: "get",
    url: "an-api-url/${task_id},
    headers: {
      "X-Auth-Token": tokenTenant
    }
  })
}`

Answer (score 4):

A few points to make:

- a promise can only resolve once.
- the callback passed to the `Promise` constructor is executed immediately, and never again afterwards

Solution: Move the `const promise1 = ...` definition inside the loop. That way you create a new promise each iteration.

Comment: Wooohooo!  You sir are a machine!  Thanks so much.  It works like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

This is one of the more common misconceptions about promises. It's not *using* the promise that calls the function you pass into `new Promise` (the *executor function* as it's called), it's *creating* the promise. That code (in the executor) is also called synchronously: `setTimeout` gets called before `promise1` receives the promise (and then its callback happens about two seconds later).

In your code, you're setting up **one** `setTimeout` call, and then waiting for it to complete, and then if the loop repeats, you wait *for that same result* a second time. (Of course, you get it much faster that time, because the timeout is already complete.)

To retry your operation, you need to create the promise *within* your loop, so you re-run the code in the executor function:

```
function getTask() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      resolve(tasks(resStatus.data.task.id, tokenTenant))
    }, 2000);
  });
}

do {
  respo = await getTask();
  console.log(respo.data)
} while (respo.data.status === "Processing" || respo.data.status === "Received");
```

I've used a traditional function for `getTask` for clarity. If you like, you can make it an arrow function instead (along with the other ones):

```
const getTask = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve(tasks(resStatus.data.task.id, tokenTenant))
  }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: And the other benefit of this approach is it separates out the `getTask` function from the main block, so it can live in a library and be reused in other code.

Comment: Thanks for the info!  Appreciate the advice. 

I have updated my code as per @trincot's suggestion.  Will try yours as well.

Comment: @RichS, I hear you.  That makes absolute sense